# What's your diagnosis?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Being what you think you are would mean you cannot think.
>   Being what you really are means you're wrong in having this.

What am I?

Hint 1:

> [image]

Think about:

> What kind of fish depicted in this piece of *art*?  What could the switched-up order mean?

Hint 2:

> [image]

Think about:

> What kind of animal are these *Docs* working on?  What could the switched-up image mean?

Hint 3:

> [image]

Think about:

> What makes this *car* unique?  What could the switched-up image mean?

Hint 4:

> [image]

Hint 5:

> The last word of the title is meant quite literally.  The previous hints are important for their subject matter.  The strange alterations hint at how to make use of all the hints.

*Special thanks to Rand Al'Thor for helping me work out the kinks in this riddle.*

Comment: Note:  The idea for the riddle was entirely mine, but I consulted a puzzler far superior to myself to polish it up.

Comment: ...are your edits hints in & of themselves? Of did you just change your mind on how to represent your first hint?

Comment: @Alconja - Very perceptive...

Comment: @WadCheber Are you looking for something specific like "Capgras Syndrome" or "Dsylexia" ?

Comment: @kanchirk - Yes, I am, but neither of those.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is it

> [Cotard Delusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotard_delusion)?

Because you

> certainly can't think if you're actually dead, and you can't be dead if you actively have this delusion.

Also

> Dot car, rat doc, Dr Taco, cod art.

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 14):

*What am I?*

Well, I'd say that looking at this riddle, I am:

> **Confused**

---

*Being what you think you are would mean you cannot think.*

> If you think you are confused you are "unable to think clearly".

*Being what you really are means you're wrong in having this.*

> But what I really am is correct, and if I'm correct, I mustn't actually have the confusion I thought I did...

Comment: Interesting and creative, but unfortunately, incorrect.

Comment: @WadCheber: When you say it is incorrect, you need to say why or else I cannot see why this is not a valid answer. Please do not expect us to be psychic.

Comment: How can I say why it is wrong without giving away the answer?

Comment: @Abhijit - I added another hint.

Comment: Here's why both answers are incorrect:  neither "reflection" nor "confused" are diagnoses, let alone the specific diagnosis I am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is

> reflection

Being what you think you are would mean you cannot think.

> If you think you are your reflection and its real than you cannot think as the reflection is just an image without cognitive capabilities.

Being what you really are means you're wrong in having this.

> But the reflection is just you so if you think your reflection is thinking, it is nevertheless you who it is thinking.

Image Hints

The Fish

> The first and the third are the mirror images. The second piece is the original one.

The Mouse

> The reflection is on a glass table.

The Car

> It is a reflection on a clear lake.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  Also, it's a rat, not a mouse.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Species Dysphoria

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_dysphoria)

??

Comment: No, but you're in the right medical field, and the right degree of obscurity.  Even the right sort of disorder - thinking you're something you're not - but the solution has nothing to do with animals.

Comment: @WadCheber Given the accepted answer, I would think this, or indeed any disorder where someone believes they are something non-sentient, would fit the riddle just as well. (Except the hints, but a puzzle should generally be capable of being solved without the hints, otherwise they're not really hints but part of the puzzle.)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Bipolar Disorder

Explanation follows.....

Being what you think you are would mean you cannot think.
Being what you really are means you're wrong in having this.

> There are two personalities.. Bi and being in one of the episodes you cannot think straight and are obnoxious. If you are aware and know you are, you can control it and you are not in the episode.

Hint 1

> Not in Order or read the picture of fish as DisOrdered.

Hint 2 and Hint 3

> Can mean "cannot think right" so the whole context is are upside down.

Comment: Right field of medicine, wrong diagnosis.  We're looking for something much more obscure.

Comment: I was initially thinking your second guess based off order/orientation of the hints, but it didn't seem to make too much sense for the original clue.

Comment: Not quite.  I've expanded on the hints.

Answer (score 1):

> Clinical lycanthropy

Has to do with thinking you're an animal or transforming into one, and is normally associated with "Reality-Bending mental state" (Delusions/Hallucinations) which could explain hint 3 with the crazy upside down car.

Comment: Not quite.  Nothing to do with animals.  But you're in the right ballpark.